# Cannot import latest (0.12.2) statsmodels.api: getting TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

Cannot import `statsmodels.api as sm,` however `import statsmodels` seems to work and the 0.12.2 version of `statsmodles`package is installed. But I can't really use statsmodels without the `api`. If I just `import statsmodels` when I try to call `statsmodels.api.OLS(y,x)` I get the `AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'api'`.  The main error I get when I try to `import statsmodels.api as sm` is pasted below. NB: all the latest dependencies are installed, I'm using python 3.8.5.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .nonparametric import api as nonparametric
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\api.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .kernel_density import \
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\kernel_density.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ._kernel_base import GenericKDE, EstimatorSettings, gpke, \
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\_kernel_base.py", line 12, in <module>
    import joblib
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .executor import get_memmapping_executor
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .externals.loky.reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .backend.reduction import set_loky_pickler
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 125, in <module>
    from joblib.externals import cloudpickle  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cloudpickle import *
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 152, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 133, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your joblib install.  You should try upgrading this, `pip install joblib --upgrade`

Comment: Hi Kevin! Thank you for your reply it indeed worked: I have had joblib 0.13.2 installed when I have upgraded it to 1.0.1 imported statsmodels.api without a problem. Perhaps, it might be a good idea to add this to docs Installation>Dependencies, as joblib >=0.9 is just in the optionals list now.